# Batch processing of new hdfs directory not processed yet

Tags: python, directory, hdfs, batch-processing, data-processing

I want to apply batch processing on Data available on HDFS directory,
it's working by changing manually the path

```
    hdfsdir = r"hdfs://VPS-DATA1:9000/directory"
    filelist = [ line.rsplit(None,1)[-1] for line in sh.hdfs('dfs','-ls',hdfsdir).split('\n') if len(line.rsplit(None,1))][1:]
    filepaths=filelist
    for path in filepaths:
        #reading data from HDFS 
        with hdfs.open(path, "r") as read_file:
....
```

I want to do it dynamically without changing the path each time : `hdfsdir = r"hdfs://VPS-DATA1:9000/directory"`, for example If a sub directory is already processed, it wwill not be processed again if I run the script again.

You see ...

I want to process only sub directories which aren't processed yet !

I am thinking to store just folder name in some data base when it's processed , so that the script will not process it

any help will be appreciated §§

thanks

Answer (score 0):

the soulution is to save the path of each hdfs directory processed in a text file, then to check before processing if the folder name exist in the text file,

so if yes: do processing of all files existing in the directory

if not: move on to the next folder and apply the same concept